# can i let a fixed text dissapear after the banner?

Tags: html, css, fixed, banner

[image][image]At the moment i have a fixed text, and a fixed navbar in my banner.
i would  like the text to dissapear after the banner image. the navbar is alright to stay fixed for the entire page. but i would prefer the text to disappear after the image! is there a way to set a boundary for a fixed element. or else is there a way to get the fixed text on the background so it will not appears over my main content but rather behind it. Thanks guy's!!

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: font-family: myriad-pro, sans-serif;
  position:relative;
  
}


.text {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position:fixed;
  top: 200px;
  color: white;
  border-style: none;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 80%;
  font-family: myriad-pro, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-style: italic;
  border-style: none;
}

#text2{
  margin-left: 200px;
  font-weight: 100;
  opacity: 60%;
  margin-top: -40px; 
  
  
}

.image {
  filter: brightness(40%);
}

li:hover{
  background-color: darkgrey;
}


li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: aqua;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  font-family: myriad-pro, sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  
  
  
}
a.list{ 
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: 20px;
}


.navbar {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 53%;
  width: 100%;
  position:static;
  top: 20%;
  border-style: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: 80px;
  z-index: 9;
}

.logo{
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-top: -11px;
}

.marcel{
  display: block;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  margin: 250px 250px;
  text-align: center;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./test.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/wbf4zoi.css">
  <title>Edusolut</title>

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
  
    <ul>
      <li><a class="list" href="#"> Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="list" href="#"> Service</a></li>
      <li><a class="list" href="#"> Contact</a></li>
      <li><a class="list" href="#"> Training</a></li>
    </ul>
      
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="logo3.png" width="120px" />
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div role="banner">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="./computer-2565478_1280.jpg" alt="computer" height="630rem" width="100%">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <h1>Edusolut</h1>
      <div id="text2">
        <p>Your Education Solution.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
  
<body id="main">
  <div class = "marcel" >
    <img src="./marcel.png">
    
    <h3> Netwerk en Trainig consultancy</h3>
```

Comment: What you want to achieve is done with JS, not CSS buddy.

Comment: I really want to help you, and as mentioned above, this is done using js or jquery. But it’s not entirely clear to me which text should disappear, and at what point ?! Can you show the problem on the screenshot?

Comment: allright i added the screenshots of the problem. i start to think it will get complicated without js. so if it is not possible is there a way to get the text behind the content instead of in front of the content i dont mind if the object is on the background only if it runs through the text it will be hard to read.

Comment: allright thanks guys